# How to show the top 4 processes to another file using Bash commands?

Tags: bash, shell

[image: processes]
I'd like to get top 4 processes to another file, instead of all it!

I know how to transfer all the data from "top" command to a new file, but again, just one top 4 instead all of it. I think it has something to do with grep command...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    top | head  -17 | tail -10 > file
```

Since top output (in my pc) has 7 lines prior to the actual process list you select first 17 lines `head -17`
Then keep those last lines 10 containing actual data related to processes: `tail -10`

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to limit the lines to be captured to the top 4 lines then output to a new file.

```
$ top -n1 | awk 'NR >= 7 && NR <= 11' > new_file
```

Comment: One more question, if I do echo `top -n1 | awk 'NR >= 7 && NR <= $count' ` It didn't show anything when I do that. I'm trying to do a loop where count can add +1 every times until it hits 12

Comment: @Ale If the variable is already initialized then you can do `top -n1 | awk -v count="$count" 'NR >= 7 && NR < count' > new_file` You do not need `echo`